# 'org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not add zip entry' happend when using shadowJar and jackson-core

Tags: java, jackson, minecraft, jackson-databind, shadowjar

When I used shadowJar to package the kotlin program, the "Could not add zip" problem occurred.
the `build.gradle.kts` as shown.

```kotlin
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("java")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.9.22"
    id("io.papermc.paperweight.userdev") version "1.5.11"
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "8.1.1"
}

group = "com.angel"
version = "0.1"

repositories {
//    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        setUrl("https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/public")
        name = "aliyun"
    }

    maven {
        name = "papermc-repo"
        setUrl("https://repo.papermc.io/repository/maven-public/")
    }
    maven {
        name = "sonatype"
        setUrl("https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/")
    }
    maven {
        name = "aikar"
        setUrl("https://repo.aikar.co/content/groups/aikar/" )
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.mybatis-flex:mybatis-flex-kotlin-extensions:1.0.5")
    implementation("com.mybatis-flex:mybatis-flex-core:1.7.9")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.16.1")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.16.1")
    annotationProcessor("com.mybatis-flex:mybatis-flex-processor:1.7.9")
    implementation("com.alibaba:druid:1.2.21")
    implementation("com.zaxxer:HikariCP:5.1.0")
    implementation("co.aikar:acf-paper:0.5.1-SNAPSHOT")
//    implementation("org.parboiled:parboiled-java:1.4.1")
    // Other Dependencies
    paperweight.paperDevBundle("1.20.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT")
}




tasks {
    assemble {
        dependsOn(reobfJar) 
    }
    build {
        dependsOn(shadowJar)  
    }
    withType<JavaCompile> {
        options.encoding = "UTF-8"
        options.compilerArgs.addAll(arrayOf("-parameters"))
    }

    withType<KotlinCompile> {

        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "17"

            freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjvm-default=all")
            kotlinOptions.javaParameters = true //  cant understand
        }
    }

    withType<Jar> {
        //  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44197521/gradle-project-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-kotlin-jvm-internal-intrinsics

        // Otherwise you'll get a "No main manifest attribute" error
        manifest {
            attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.angel.mc.MiniRPG"
        }

        // To avoid the duplicate handling strategy error
        duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE

        // To add all of the dependencies
        from(sourceSets.main.get().output)

        dependsOn(configurations.runtimeClasspath)
        from({
            configurations.runtimeClasspath.get().filter { it.name.endsWith("jar") }.map { zipTree(it) }
        })
    }

    shadowJar {

        
        relocate("co.aikar.commands", "com.angel.mc.lib.acf")
        relocate("co.aikar.locales", "com.angel.mc.lib.locales")
    }
}



java {
    withSourcesJar()
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

}



kotlin {

}


tasks.register<Copy>("copy2plugin") {
    group = "build"

    dependsOn("build")
    doFirst {

    }
    from(layout.buildDirectory.dir("libs/miniRPG-0.1.jar"))
    into("$projectDir/paper/plugins")

}
```

An error occurred in the "shadowJar" task when I executed the "copy2plugin" task:
`Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not add zip entry xxx\jackson-core-2.16.1.jar!META-INF/versions/21/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/io/doubleparser/FastDoubleSwar.class to ZIP 'xxx\build\libs\miniRPG-0.1-dev-all.jar'.` 
[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqQF5.png)

The detailed error information is as follows:

```
Execution failed for task ':shadowJar'.
> Cannot expand ZIP 'C:\Users\20666\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\2.16.1\9456bb3cdd0f79f91a5f730a1b1bb041a380c91f\jackson-core-2.16.1.jar'.

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':shadowJar'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:149)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:147)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:135)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:337)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:324)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:317)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:303)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:463)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:380)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Cannot expand ZIP 'C:\Users\20666\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\2.16.1\9456bb3cdd0f79f91a5f730a1b1bb041a380c91f\jackson-core-2.16.1.jar'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.archive.ZipFileTree.lambda$visit$0(ZipFileTree.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheCoordinator.useCache(DefaultCacheCoordinator.java:248)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheCoordinator.useCache(DefaultCacheCoordinator.java:229)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:203)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.useCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:229)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultDecompressionCache.useCache(DefaultDecompressionCache.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.archive.ZipFileTree.visit(ZipFileTree.java:81)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.FilteredMinimalFileTree.visit(FilteredMinimalFileTree.java:84)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.FileTreeAdapter.visit(FileTreeAdapter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileTree.visit(CompositeFileTree.java:108)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopySpecActionImpl.execute(CopySpecActionImpl.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopySpecActionImpl.execute(CopySpecActionImpl.java:25)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DefaultCopySpec$DefaultCopySpecResolver.walk(DefaultCopySpec.java:779)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DefaultCopySpec$DefaultCopySpecResolver.walk(DefaultCopySpec.java:781)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DefaultCopySpec.walk(DefaultCopySpec.java:519)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopySpecBackedCopyActionProcessingStream.process(CopySpecBackedCopyActionProcessingStream.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator.lambda$execute$1(DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator.java:47)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.NormalizingCopyActionDecorator.lambda$execute$1(NormalizingCopyActionDecorator.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopyActionProcessingStream$process.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowCopyAction$2.execute(ShadowCopyAction.groovy:108)
    at com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowCopyAction$2$execute.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.intercept.CallInterceptorsSet$DecoratingCallSite.access$101(CallInterceptorsSet.java:128)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.intercept.CallInterceptorsSet$DecoratingCallSite$1.callOriginal(CallInterceptorsSet.java:140)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.Instrumented$ProcessGroovyMethodsExecuteInterceptor.doIntercept(Instrumented.java:830)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.intercept.CallInterceptorsSet$DecoratingCallSite.call(CallInterceptorsSet.java:137)
    at com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowCopyAction.withResource(ShadowCopyAction.groovy:150)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowCopyAction.execute(ShadowCopyAction.groovy:105)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.NormalizingCopyActionDecorator.execute(NormalizingCopyActionDecorator.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator.execute(DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator.java:47)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopyActionExecuter.execute(CopyActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.AbstractCopyTask.copy(AbstractCopyTask.java:149)
    at com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar.copy(ShadowJar.java:161)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:125)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$3.run(TaskExecution.java:242)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeAction(TaskExecution.java:227)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeActions(TaskExecution.java:210)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(TaskExecution.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.execute(TaskExecution.java:166)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:105)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:67)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:28)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.executeDelegateBroadcastingChanges(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:100)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:72)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:166)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.lambda$execute$1(BuildCacheStep.java:70)
    at org.gradle.internal.Either$Right.fold(Either.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.caching.CachingState.fold(CachingState.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:25)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:65)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:94)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNonEmptySources(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:177)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:86)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:21)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:23)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupStaleOutputsStep.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsStep.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupStaleOutputsStep.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsStep.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$4.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:287)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:21)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:146)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:135)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:337)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:324)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:317)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:303)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:463)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:380)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not add zip entry C:\Users\20666\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\2.16.1\9456bb3cdd0f79f91a5f730a1b1bb041a380c91f\jackson-core-2.16.1.jar!META-INF/versions/21/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/io/doubleparser/FastDoubleSwar.class to ZIP 'D:\software\idea\workspace\mc_plugin\miniRPG\build\libs\miniRPG-0.1-dev-all.jar'.
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.intercept.CallInterceptorsSet$DecoratingCallSite.access$401(CallInterceptorsSet.java:128)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.intercept.CallInterceptorsSet$DecoratingCallSite$4.callOriginal(CallInterceptorsSet.java:180)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.intercept.CallInterceptorsSet$1.doIntercept(CallInterceptorsSet.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.intercept.CallInterceptorsSet$DecoratingCallSite.callConstructor(CallInterceptorsSet.java:177)
    at com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowCopyAction$StreamAction.visitFile(ShadowCopyAction.groovy:243)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor937.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowCopyAction$BaseStreamAction.processFile(ShadowCopyAction.groovy:181)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.NormalizingCopyActionDecorator.lambda$execute$0(NormalizingCopyActionDecorator.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator.lambda$execute$0(DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator.java:65)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopyFileVisitorImpl.processFile(CopyFileVisitorImpl.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopyFileVisitorImpl.visitFile(CopyFileVisitorImpl.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.FilteredMinimalFileTree$2.visitFile(FilteredMinimalFileTree.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.archive.ZipFileTree.lambda$visit$0(ZipFileTree.java:102)
    ... 152 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 65
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:199)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:180)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:287)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor401.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowCopyAction$StreamAction.remapClass(ShadowCopyAction.groovy:339)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor944.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowCopyAction$StreamAction.remapClass(ShadowCopyAction.groovy:325)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor941.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowCopyAction$StreamAction.visitFile(ShadowCopyAction.groovy:239)
    ... 161 more
```

It seems that jackson-core uses java21 somewhere(`Unsupported class file major version 65`), and shadowJar's gradle plugin doesn't support it. My project uses java17, and I can't reduce or improve the version of java, how can I avoid this error?

I tried [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77165413/parboiled-under-java-21-unsupported-class-file-major-version-65) mentioned method, But it didn't work.